# Связать LDAP, MSSQL, PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ldap

Имеется сервер MSSQL и настроенные логины-пользрватели, привязанные к доменным учеткам. Хочу связать web приложение с базой так, чтобы при аутентификации пользователи вводили доменные учетные данные и по ним же получали доступ к базе. При этом, хочу использовать окно ввода логина-пароля из web приложения, а не стандартное окно браузера(когда выставляю windows аутентификацию в IIS). Какой метод аутентификации использовать в MSSQL, IIS? Как пройти аутентификацию средствами php в ldap и использовать эти данные для аутентификации в MSSQL?

Comment: >а не стандартное окно браузера(когда выставляю windows аутентификацию в IIS) Это ты имел ввиду http авторизацию? Ну схема на самом деле простая, делаешь обычную форму авторизации на сайте что бы не использовать *"окно браузера"* (http авторизацию) Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку войти у тебя в POST запросе передается логин и пароль от LDAP юзера, у php есть расширение для работы с LDAP http://php.net/manual/ru/book.ldap.php Далее юзая любу по ссылке проверяеш что пользователь логин пароль есть в LDAP Подключаешся к БД под этой учеткой, сложности вроде нет. Или я что то упустил?

Comment: Удалось реализовать? Очень актуальная для меня тема, подскажите пожалуйста как.

Comment: Да, реализовал следующим образом: создается пользователь в АД и пользователь в MSSQL с таким же именем, но с паролем, которому назначаются права в базе. При запуске php скрипта, сначала проверяется правильность ввода логина-пароля в АД, если верно, то тогда этот логин используется для подключения к базе.

Comment: Вы бы не могли поделиться исходным кодом на php ? Я в этом мало волоку особо.
Спасибо большое заранее

Answer (score 0):

> а не стандартное окно браузера(когда выставляю windows аутентификацию в IIS)

Это ты имел ввиду http авторизацию? 
Ну схема на самом деле простая, делаешь обычную форму авторизации на сайте что бы не использовать *"окно браузера"* (http авторизацию) 
Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку войти у тебя в POST запросе передается логин и пароль от LDAP юзера, у php есть расширение для работы с LDAP 
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.ldap.php 
Далее юзая любу по ссылке проверяеш что пользователь логин пароль есть в LDAP 
Подключаешся к БД под этой учеткой, сложности вроде нет. Или я что то упустил?

Comment: Да, вроде все так, но в таком случае, почему то(может что не докрутил) mssql отвечает что логин или пароль не верен. При этом, если с той же формы отключить ldap авторизацию и попробоваться подключиться к базе через учетку созданную как mssql-скую - все отлично логинится и получает доступ к базе. А получить доступ через учетку привязанную к ldap  логину - получаю ошибку. Может это быть связано с тем что версия mssql - express?

Comment: Сколько смотрю примеров, для использования windows аутентификации в mssql нужно передать только сервер и имя экземпляра из php скрипта. Но в таком случае, понятное дело, происходит попытка подключения под пользователем iis_user...